# Reiniciar o layout

Tags: java, android

Eu fiz dois botões que setam adapter no recyclerview, cada botão seta um layout diferente, porém só fazendo isso

```
findViewById(R.id.layout2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            recyclerView adapter = new recyclerView(R.layout.listlayout);
            RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            rv.swapAdapter(adapter,true);
            rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext()));

        }
    });
```

não funcionou, ele seta apenas uma vez, caso queira trocar o layout ele não altera, tentei também

```
Intent main = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
finish();
startActivity(main);
```

porém ao fazer isso ele seta o adapter e reinicia, perdendo assim o adapter.
Queria saber se alguém tem uma outra forma de fazer isso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

é só usar no lugar do `swapAdapter(adapter, true)` o  `setAdapter(adapter)`

Answer (score 4):

No lugar de:

```
rv.swapAdapter(adapter,true);
```

use:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```